# How to get specific date from days, number of week and year

Tags: php, date

I want get specific date based on days, number of week and years,

```
$days = "Monday";
$number_of_week = date('W'); // 1 to 42 total number of weeks in years
$year = date('Y'); // 2017

getSpecificDate($days, $number_of_week, $year);
```

it will return

> 2017-02-20

How to get that?

Comment: What should be ur output? do u need to get the current date or something else? can you brief your quesion

Comment: please tell me what is your desire result

Comment: When working with ISO-8601 weeks, don't use `Y` for year, but use `o`, which is ISO-8601 week-numbering year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$days = "Tuesday";
$number_of_week = date('W'); // 1 to 42 total number of weeks in years
$year = date('Y'); // 2017

function getSpecificDate($days, $number_of_week, $year){
   $week_day = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($year."W".$number_of_week) );

   $date_time = strtotime($week_day.' next '.$days);

   return date('Y-m-d', $date_time);
}

echo getSpecificDate($days, $number_of_week, $year);
```

Comment: thank you sir, its work, but it should return this
$week_day = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($year."W".$number_of_week) ); and it work.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The function like this:

$year : year

$week : if 1~9, should prepended 0, like 01~09

$days : 1~7

```
getSpecificDate($days, $week, $year) {

    return date("Y-m-d", strtotime($year . "W" . sprintf("%02u", $week) . $days)); 

}
```

Comment: Output is wrong. if $day = "Monday" then the output is 2017-02-21 where it should be 2017-02-20

Comment: already solve using mith method
i should return $week_day = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($year."W".$number_of_week) );

thanks for helping, m(_ _)m